# "hoch" im Sinn von "hinauf/herauf" - umgangssprachlich oder standard?

Tags: regional, standard-german

Bei Sprechern aus der Bundesrepublik hört man oft "hoch" im Sinn von "hinauf" oder "herauf" (z.B. "Ich gehe die Treppe hoch"), während es in Österreich ausschliesslich im Sinn von engl. "high" verwendet wird.

Wird diese Verwendung in Deutschland als hochsprachlich betrachtet oder handelt es sich um eine umgangssprachliche Ausdrucksweise? Wie sieht es mit dem Gebrauch im Schriftdeutschen aus?

Comment: [Weltrekord im Treppe *hochgehen*](http://www.langweiledich.net/2012/01/weltrekord-im-mit-dem-kopf-die-treppe-hochgehen/) ;)

Comment: B2T: ngram Vergleich zw. [Treppe hoch und Treppe hinauf](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Treppe+hoch%2C+Treppe+hinauf&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3) und [Treppe runter und Treppe hinab](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Treppe+runter%2CTreppe+hinab&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3) (Anm.: Ähnlich, wenn man Treppe durch Leiter ersetzt)

Comment: ngram fuehrt hier in die Irre; wenn man sich die Suchergebnisse zu 1800-1809 ansieht, dann findet man "Treppe hoch" meist in der bedeutung von "high", mit "eine Treppe" als Maßeinheit: "In dem zweiten Stockwerk, eine Treppe hoch, sind die Wohn - und Schlafzimmer der Herrschaft"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Duden hat einen Eintrag für "hoch"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hoch_hinauf_empor) in der Bedeutung "hinauf". Dazu ist keine Angabe zum Gebrauch gemacht, wie es bei umganssprachlichen oder regional begrenzten Ausdrücken üblicherweise geschieht. Daraus würde ich lesen, dass "hoch" in der angegebenen Bedeutung (bundesdeutsch) standardsprachlich ist und es keine Einwände gegen den Gebrauch im Schriftdeutschen gibt.

Comment: Duden hat aber auch nen Eintrag extra für [hochgehen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hochgehen), wo leider kein Treppenbeispiel gelistet ist, jedoch z.b. die Straße hochgehen, vor Wut hochgehen, etc. Dennoch ist die Erklärung "sich nach oben, in die Höhe bewegen" recht eindeutig. Nett finde ich noch, dass Duden aber [die Treppe hochfallen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Karriere_machen) listet, wobei ich in der Praxis eher die wortgetreue als die figurative Verwendung höre.

Comment: Auch im ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch) findet man "hochgehen": Die Sprengladung geht hoch | (ugs.) sich erregen | sich entrüsten. Aber im österreichischen Deutsch kann man keine Treppe hoch gehen. Denn wenn wir nach unten wollen, gehen wir Österreicher ja auch nicht die Treppe tief, sondern hinunter.

Comment: Antwort "unter Protest akzeptiert". Es ist frustrierend, das der Duden keine Unterscheidung zwischen regionalen Gewohnheiten in Deutschland und der gemeinsamen deutschen Hochsprache trifft.